# Casting to a custom ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I have created a custom ArrayList object and recieve an error when trying to cast to this object. I think I have misunderstood something as I expected this to work. If I have a custom ArrayList object that will only treat an ArrayList of Integers:

```
public class CustomArrayList extends ArrayList<Integer>{

    public void customMethod() {
        // do things with integer arraylist
    }
}
```

I expect that I could cast a List of Integers like the following:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
((CustomArrayList) myList).customMethod();
```

But this results in a cast class exception. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong and how to successfully achieve the cast? Thanks

Comment: Change `new ArrayList<>()` to `new CustomArrayList()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CustomArrayList` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`, but an `ArrayList<Integer>` is not a `CustomArrayList`.

If you want to convert an arbitrary `ArrayList<Integer>` to a `CustomArrayList`, you can write:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
CustomArrayList customList = new CustomArrayList(myList);
customList.customMethod();
```

This will require adding a constructor to `CustomArrayList` that accepts a `Collection<Integer>` and passes it to `ArrayList`'s `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c` constructor.

```
public CustomArrayList(Collection<Integer> c) {
    super(c);
}
```

Note that the `CustomArrayList` instance created with this constructor is a copy of the original `ArrayList`, so changes in that instance won't be reflected in the original `List`.

Comment: Life saver! Exactly what I was looking for, and helped me understand why it wasn't working too. Thanks a bunch!